# e.target.form.name is returning the target instead of the form name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, dom

I have a modal that contains multiple forms and I need to access the name of the particular form that is being edited to update the correct data.

My onChange handler is:

```
const onFormChange = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    const target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
    if (target.name === undefined || target.name === '') {
      return;
    }
    const targetForm = target.form;
    const formName = (targetForm || { name: '' }).name;
    ...
    //handle updating data

}
```

Logs I added show that the value of `targetForm` is correct, returning:

```
<form name="createUser">
...
</form>
```

However, next when I try to extract the string "createUser" by using:

```
const formName = (targetForm || { name: '' }).name;
```

instead of the string, `formName` returns the div element of the original target:

```
<input name='email' type='text' id='1'>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening or how I can access the form.name correctly?

Comment: Try `e.target.closest("form").name`

Comment: `target.closest("form").name` is still returning the target element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by getting form name via

```
const formName = targetForm ? targetForm.getAttribute('name') || '' : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

The type React.FormEvent doesn't contain the form name, you can use the BaseSyntheticEvent to pull the form name where the input is being changed.

```
onChange={(e: React.BaseSyntheticEvent): void => {
 console.log(e.target.form.name);
 ....
 ...
 ..
}}
```